# Gradle `DependencyHandler` add kapt dependency which doesn't add to `kaptClasspath`

Tags: android, gradle

I am write a `Gradle Plugin`, which will auto add kapt denepency to `project.dependencies`, but it doesn't work.

Code like as following:

```kotlin
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.dependencies.add("kapt", "group:artifactId:version")
}
```

But if I add kapt in `build.gradle`, it will work.

After I execute dependencies command, I found the kapt dependency is not added to kaptClasspath.

```
kaptClasspath_kaptDebugKotlin
No dependencies
```

which should be something like as following:

```
kaptClasspath_kaptDebugKotlin
\--- group:artifactId:version
```

So, is there someone met the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today.

then I test in `build.gradle`.

```
  afterEvaluate {
        dependencies {
            kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2' //no work
        }
    }
```

may `AbstractProcessor`  work before `afterEvaluate`

so I remove `afterEvaluate`

```
 override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.dependencies.apply {
            project.dependencies.add("kapt", "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2") //it work
        }
 }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31478282)